# Bidirectional LSTM input vs feature size in PyTorch

Tags: python, input, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have found an interesting anomaly where for Bi-directional LSTM I get somewhat higher accuracy when I double the input size to how many features my dataset contains. I cannot figure why this happens. The only thing that comes to mind is that since the input is fed both forward and backward for BLSTM, it makes the size of it double in PyTorch and by setting input_size==num_of_features I actually force it to embed it to half. Can somebody confirm/reject this hypothesis, ideally with some sources cited?

Any help is greatly appreciated.